# Odata with Olingo or Odata4j

Tags: java, mule, odata, odata4j, olingo

I'm in over my head.

At the broadest level, I'm trying to expose an Odata interface to an existing pool of data exposed by a service written using Mule.  When my Mule service is invoked, if I detect that the URL is Odata format, I want to delegate processing down to something written in Java and then feed the response from that component back to my caller.

I found the Olingo and OData4j libraries.  My problem is that these start from building a Web service.  But that's too far upstream for me.   I have a Web service.  What I need to understand are what components I need to implement in order to pass the URL (which I have in hand) onward to an Odata parser which will, in turn, invoke a data provider.

I'm a bit lost with this technology.  Can someone point me to a very basic tutorial that clearly delineates this.  Or, can they give me a couple steps like:  "You have to implement A, B & C and then pass your URL into C.foo()"?

I've tried the Getting Started doc for both libraries but they both start with "first we'll implement a Web service" and don't clearly delineate (to me, at least) where that leaves off and pure Odata sets in.

Thanks.

Comment: For future visitors, you can check out the Northwind example at http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

Answer (score 4):

The following is the code that will help you to get started for using data from a service exposing via OData.(using Apache Olingo).

```
 URL url=new URL(/*your url*/);
 HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
 conn.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,HttpContentType.APPLICATION_XML);
 conn.connect();
 InputStream content=conn.getInputStream();
 Edm edm = EntityProvider.readMetadata(content, false);
```

After this you can use static methods of EntityProvider class for carrying out various operations like read,update,write

If you are using odata4j go with the following code

```
   ODataConsumer demo_consumer= ODataConsumers.create(/*your URL*/);
   Enumerable<EntitySetInfo> demo_entitySetList = demo_consumer.getEntitySets();


    for (EntitySetInfo entitySet : entitySetList) {
      System.out.println(entitySet.getHref());
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

this sounds very like how we read rss or other data feeds

Since you have a url, this can be read by a Http Connector or even a polling http connector.
The data can be streamed using a Java input stream the default behavior or converted to a string (object to string).

A simple java component using (OData4j) can process your content .. it sounds like 2 simple components on a mule flow.

R